# Special characters in script not working correctly

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script to change a password on multiple servers. The issue is that the password has special characters. This is the example of the echo command I am using:

```
echo -e "'P#7g$dkW$8Ej$5$%'\n'P#7g$dkW$8Ej$5$%'"
```

Here is the response:

```
[root@myserver ~]# echo -e "'P#7g$dkW$8Ej$5$%'\n'P#7g$dkW$8Ej$5$%'"
'P#7gEj$%'
'P#7gEj$%'
```

As you can see it is dropping a lot of characters. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is best avoided -- see [the POSIX standard for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections, which recommend using `printf` instead any time input contains backslashes. `printf '%s\n%s\n' "$foo" "$foo"` will print the exact contents of `$foo` twice with a newline between them, **without** trying to treat those contents as a format string as well (which your current code does, so if a password contained the string `\t` it would be substituted with a tab, or `\n` with a newline, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your string is interpreted that way is because you have used double-quotes to create the string. The single quote that you have set after that will be interpreted as a part of the string and has no special meaning anymore and doesn't make your password a literal string. That means that the password string is still in the scope of "" and $xyz will be interpreted as the xyz variable.

You can try to concatenate them like this

```
passwd1='password1'
passwd2='password2'
echo -e "$passwd1\n$passwd2"
```

or just leave out the double quotes in your solution.

Comment: The OP rather clearly wants a literal newline; your current code doesn't give them that. And the trailing and leading whitespace isn't correct either -- that'll be considered part of the password by the code reading it in.

Comment: This (`echo -e`) is buggy when arbitrary passwords are allowed: If your password has `\t` in it it'll become a tab, `\n` will become an extra newline, etc. See my comment on the question with links to the relevant POSIX sh standard.

Comment: (and also `echo -e` isn't even available on all builds of bash: If it's compiled with `--enable-xpg-echo-default`, then `echo -e` will just print `-e` on output when the shell is in POSIX mode).

Answer (score 0):

Take out the double quotes and just use single quotes so variables (preceded by `$`) aren't expanded.